# Generate random string with python for a string(mix of int and chars) with particular lenght

Tags: python, pandas, random, faker

Need to generate random string as follows

first 5 strings should be alphabet in caps 
Next 4 should be integers and 
one alphabet at last

output i need examples:

```
ACCE1664Z
BCED1782V
FBCR9126N
```

it is generating random string.

Comment: What does this have to do with `pandas`? Besides, what have you tried so far?

Comment: updatred pl chk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from string import ascii_uppercase, digits
import random 

def generatestr():
    str0= random.sample(ascii_uppercase,4)+random.sample(digits,4)+random.sample(ascii_uppercase,1)
    return ''.join(str0)

print(generatestr())
```

Improvement from @ComplicatedPhenomenon's Answer

Visit [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html) for more string constants (e.g. `ascii_uppercase`).

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the last alphabet is also in caps.

```
import random 
def generatestr():
    alphabet = []
    for letter in range(65, 91):
        alphabet.append(chr(letter))
    num = [str(i) for i in range(10)]
    str0= random.sample(alphabet,4)+random.sample(num,4)+random.sample(alphabet,1)
    return ''.join(str0)
generatestr()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
import string 

def randomString(charLength, intLength):
    letters = string.ascii_uppercase
    numbers = list(range(0,9))
    charArray = ""
    numArray= ""
    for i in range(max(charLength,intLength)):
        if i < charLength:  
            charArray = charArray + random.choice(letters)
        if i < intLength:    
            numArray = numArray + str(random.choice(numbers))

    return (charArray + numArray + random.choice(letters))

print(randomString(5,4))
```